# Text based physics problems for visually impaired children

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

So I'm currently doing research on studying physics by visually impaired children. I know, that there are many techniques to teach such a kid physics, but what I don't like about these techniques is that they are mostly tactile-based and implement graphs and illustrations in Braille and real-life physical objects. Don't get me wrong - I understand, that you must compensate the lack of visuals with something, but what I am searching for is a textbook or just a collection of simple physics problems, that don't require calculations, but are well-written with detailed descriptions, so that you don't need graphs and illustrations to understand it. The closest thing to what I'm searching for is Bennett test, but this test requires visuals.

Comment: Side note - [new tactile graphics printer](http://www.bmyjet.eu/novel-braille-and-tactile-graphic-printer-wins-international-awards/) costs not that much - only `250€`